# Finding a basis of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a linear operator $T$ on $V$ find the eigenvalues of $T$ and an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix:

$V$=$R^3$, $T(a,b,c)$= $(7a-4b+10c,4a-3b+8c,-2a+b-2c)$.

I solved this question, and got that, the eigenvalues are $-1,1,2$ and

the basis $\beta$ = {$(1,2,0),(1,4,1),(-2,0,1)$}.

But, my book gives a different answer for $\beta$, i.e.

$\beta$ = {$(1,2,0),(1,-1,-1),(2,0,-1)$}.

Is my answer also correct ? What i want to know is, whether this basis $\beta$ for $V$ can be uniquely determined ?

I think that there could be many choices for $\beta$, as even the question says "$an$" ordered basis and not "$the$" ordered basis. Am i correct ?

Comment: I am not very sure about this but : there would be only one basis with which given transformation can be diagonalizable.. that basis would be eigen vectors corresponding to distinct eigen values...

Comment: btw how did you get your $\beta$ ?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik corresponding to each eigenvalue, I took $B$=$[T]_\beta$ - $\lambda$$I$ and then solved the system of equations that i got from, $B$$x$ =$0$, where $x$ is a vector in $R^3$ to get an eigenvactor corresponding to each eigenvalue and then took $\phi_\beta^-1$($x$) to get an eigenvector for $T$

Comment: I guess that should work... let some one else comment on that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* canonical choice for a basis of eigenvectors. For instance, if $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector, then also $(a,a,a)$ (for $a\ne0$) is, and there's no rule that makes $(1,1,1)$ preferable to $(2,2,2)$.

Your matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -4 & 10 \\
4 & -3 & 8 \\
-2 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It's readily checked that

1. $(1,2,0)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-1$;
2. $(1,-1,-1)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$;
3. $(2,0,-1)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $2$.

There's no canonical choice, so using $(-2,0,1)$ is as good as using $(4,0,-2)$ or $(2,0,-1)$.

However, having made the checks, your vector $(1,4,1)$ cannot be an eigenvector: if it were, it would be a scalar multiple of one of the preceding vectors, which it isn't.

Indeed
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -4 & 10 \\
4 & -3 & 8 \\
-2 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\4\\1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I had to grade your test, I'd consider this a serious mistake, because you *have* a way to check your computations, namely that the vectors you found are indeed eigenvectors.